# UsedRange throw error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to get only used range within excel worksheet , but I am getting error that says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWSheet = null;

Excel.Range xlCell = xlWSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell,Type.Missing);


Excel.Range oRng = xlWSheet.get_Range("A1", xlCell);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWSheet = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet();
```

Otherwise, your object is null and thus you are getting NullReferanceException.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you invoking member on xlWSheet which is set to `null`

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWSheet = null;
```

For example : you should have proper assignment before using it.

```
var app = new Application { Visible = true };
app.Workbooks.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWSheet = app.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: if I removed this assignment I will get error saying  Use of unassigned local variable `xlWSheet` 
at that line `Excel.Range xlCell = xlWSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell,Type.Missing);`

Comment: please like what ?

Comment: i updated answer with some example. but still it depends on context.